# Adding the Favorite/Like button post in buddypress so users can like content

Tags: buddypress

How to add the Favorite/Like button post in buddypress so users can like content.

I search and tried manything.. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

For "Like" I use the old plugin "BuddyPress Like"
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/buddypress-like/